# The following fatal alert was generated: 51. The internal error state is 1306

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate

I am working on integration solution with a payment gateway, we are using SSL3 with digital certificates to secure connection between us, I already reached their services and successfully sent request and received the response.

The problem is when they trying to consume our HTTPs services which hosted on IIS 7 on our Windows 2008 R2 server, they got below error:

```
**java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**
```

I tried to catch any errors from my-side, so I found this error in "Event Viewer\Windows Logs\System"

```
**The following fatal alert was generated: 51. The internal error state is 1306**
```

I think the request is not reached to the service; its dropped some where before the IIS.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Error 51 means there is a problem in the TLS, so please enable TLS 1.0 on the registry and increase logging of the SChannel (to get information, warnings and errors about the connection)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL]
"EventLogging"=dword:00000007

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260729